# CSS for gradient box shadow and borders

Tags: html, gradient, css

Is it possible to do this in CSS:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

here's my 2 cents:

HTML:

```
<div class="upperDiv"></div>
<div class="lowerDiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.upperDiv {
width:500px;
height: 40px;

background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center bottom, ellipse farthest-corner, #E4E4E4 0%, #FDFDFD 150%);
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center bottom, ellipse farthest-corner, #E4E4E4 0%, #FDFDFD 150%);
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center bottom, ellipse farthest-corner, #E4E4E4 0%, #FDFDFD 150%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center bottom, 0, center bottom, 567, color-stop(0, #E4E4E4), color-stop(1.5, #FDFDFD));
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center bottom, ellipse farthest-corner, #E4E4E4 0%, #FDFDFD 150%);
background-image: radial-gradient(center bottom, ellipse farthest-corner, #E4E4E4 0%, #FDFDFD 150%);

}

.lowerDiv {
width:500px;
height: 40px;

background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-corner, #FDFDFD 0%, #F0F0F0 80%);
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-corner, #FDFDFD 0%, #F0F0F0 80%);
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-corner, #FDFDFD 0%, #F0F0F0 80%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center top, 0, center top, 567, color-stop(0, #FDFDFD), color-stop(0.8, #F0F0F0));
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-corner, #FDFDFD 0%, #F0F0F0 80%);
background-image: radial-gradient(center top, ellipse farthest-corner, #FDFDFD 0%, #F0F0F0 80%);
}
```

The width and height are there just so you can see something. I think this will work on most modern browsers (though it's a bit verbose)

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I have put together. You can do some messing around with it if you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gk6xJ/

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your question, but if you need to do this (and don't have to be in css), I suppose that you already have that created in some other program, so you may find this useful: [a farewell to css3 gradients](http://designfestival.com/a-farewell-to-css3-gradients/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be approached with two divs each having a [radial gradient](http://html5.litten.com/455/). Here's a [tool to experiment](http://www.westciv.com/tools/radialgradients/index.html) with gradients. It also provides vendor-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar on a site:

```
width: 60%; height: 20px; background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center top , ellipse farthest-side, rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5), rgba(100, 100, 100, 0) 75%), -moz-radial-gradient(center top , ellipse farthest-side, rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5), rgba(200, 200, 200, 0)), -moz-radial-gradient(center top , ellipse farthest-side, rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3), rgba(200, 200, 200, 0)); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 5px, 100% 10px, 100% 15%;
```